# Copying an Excel file from Google Drive to a newly created Folder using Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

So this is the code I have for now.

```
function copyfile() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_Patients");
var activeSheetFM = ss.getSheetByName("_FolderMaker_");
var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
var data = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).getValues();
var secondData = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).getValues();
var folder_Name = [data+ ", " +secondData];

var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
var finalId = activeSheetFM.getRange(2,4,1,1).setValue(id);

//var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1g25_24OTv_t5Qav2Q1hwEM_YBiPSaWWb");
//var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1pqh74miSSy9WDSD3kpi02kkI6XDuXiuU");
//var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(finalId);
//
//var file2 = file.makeCopy('BACKUP ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + '.' + file.getName());
//dest_folder.addFile(file2);
//source_folder.removeFile(file2);
}
```

So i was aiming to get the folders name from the spreadsheet by using

```
var data = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).getValues();
var secondData = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).getValues();
var folder_Name = [data+ ", " +secondData];
```

and then combining it into an array to use on

```
var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
```

and was hoping to get the folder ID this way by setting the values back to a separate sheet

```
var finalId = activeSheetFM.getRange(2,4,1,1).setValue(id);
```

but it returns as "FolderIterator". I'm not even sure if this method is viable as I am pretty new in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues:

- The first issue in your code is that you want to get the values of **single** cells:

  ```
  var data = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).getValues();
  var secondData = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).getValues();
  ```

  but you are using `getValues` which returns a **2D** array. Therefore, you need to replace `getValues` with `getValue`.
- Last but not least, `folders` is a `FolderIterator` object as the error suggests. Namely, you need to iterate over it in the same way as in my solution. Keep in mind, that if you have multiple folders with the same name, this approach needs to be altered to get the folder of your choice. Because this approach will return multiple ids corresponding to each of the files with that name.

---

### Solution:

```
function copyfile() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_Patients");
var activeSheetFM = ss.getSheetByName("_FolderMaker_");
var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
var data = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).getValue();
var secondData = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow,4,1,1).getValue();
var folder_Name = data+ ", " +secondData;

var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
while (folders.hasNext()) {
      const folder = folders.next();
      var id = folder.getId(); 
} 
var finalId = activeSheetFM.getRange(2,4,1,1).setValue(id);
}
```

---

### Related articles:

- [What does the range method getValues() return and setValues() accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept)
- [Searching for a Google-apps-script to iterate through a folder of sheets and append a range of data to a consolidated master sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612726/searching-for-a-google-apps-script-to-iterate-through-a-folder-of-sheets-and-app)

Comment: I appreciate the help. I just noticed that at the end of the code I use .addFile which seems to be deprecated. I tried to use MoveTo but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Naeed Could you please post a new question regarding this issue ? Stackoverflow does not allow for follow-up questions. Thanks a lot and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: its fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

#### You have two main issues with this code:

## 1st issue - `getValues`

When you call `getValues`, if you have a Sheet like this:

[image]

Adn you call it on the whole range, it will return:

```
[
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
]
```

If you create a range object that only references one cell, like `A1`, you will get:

```
[[1]]
```

You can use `getValue` (without the s) to return the *actual value*. So if you use `getValue` on the range `A1`, it will return:

```
1
```

## 2nd Issue - `FolderIterator`

When you call this:

```js
var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
```

The variable `id` becomes a [`FolderIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator). So a better naming for this variable would be `folders`. Even if there is only one folder, it still returns an iterator, which you can think of like a list. To get the actual id of the folders within that list:

```js
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_Name);
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getId());
}
```

#### References

- [`getValue` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
- [`getValues` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [`getFoldersByName` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [`FolderIterator` Class description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I found similar entries on the Apps Script reference.